# Running AppManage raises error

Tags: tibco

Running `path\to\tibco\tra\5.8\bin\AppManage.exe` (from Tibco distribution) gives the following error:

> Failed to open properties file : AppManage.tra
>
> Adjustment failed.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `AppManage.exe` inside the folder `path\to\tibco\tra\5.8\bin` or adding this folder to `PATH` solves the issue.